# How does this relate to Vieta's formula?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I was reading [this PDF](http://diendantoanhoc.net/forum/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=219).

On Page 2, the author mentions Vieta's Formula. Now I am familiar with it (the fact that a quadratic, for example, can be written as $(x-a)(x-b)$ and that the sum of the roots is equal to -(coefficient) of one of the terms and so on, but I didn't quite understand the form the author was proposing. I am also familiar with symmetric polynomials and how they are related to Vieta's formula. But what does the below equation mean?

The author says, and I quote: "Vieta’s Formulas state that
$$\sigma_k={ (-1) }^k \cdot \frac { { a }_{ n-k } }{ { a }_{ k } }$$
for 1 ≤ k ≤ n."

How is this the statement of Vieta's Formula?

Could anybody elucidate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ${\sigma}_{k}$ means sum of product of the roots taken k at a time.

Comment: The author defines $\sigma_k$ just above that statement.

Comment: @L16H7 - What about **a**?

Comment: a is coefficent of the polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a mistake - the denominator should be $a_n$, which I assume is the coefficient of $x^n$ (it would be good if you put the polynomial in your question rather than a link).

Dividing through by $a_n$ is necessary to convert the polynomial to monic form.

---

For the benefit of the down voters the formula should be $$\sigma_k=(-1)^k\frac {a_{n-k}}{a_n}$$ and the formula given is $$\sigma_k=(-1)^k\frac {a_{n-k}}{a_k}$$

---

So if we have a polynomial $$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0$$ we can factorise it as $$p(x)=a_n(x-t_1)(x-t_2)\dots (x-t_n)$$ where the $t_i$ are the roots. If $\sigma_k$ is the $k_{th}$ symmetric polynomial in the roots $t_i$ we can expand the factorisation to give $$p(x)=a_nx^n-a_n\sigma_1x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n(-1)^n\sigma _n$$

and the formula follows by equating coefficients.

Comment: Could you please elucidate on the formula?

Comment: I was also thinking there must have been a typo...